# How to get Custom Table of Content in Aspose.word using C#

Tags: c#, wpf, aspose.words

I am working in Report and using Aspose.word. I need to get customize Table of content. But in Word its giving only default template like as below,

Heading 1.............................. 1

Heading 1.1...........................2

Heading 1.2...........................3

But I need Table of content as below,

(1-3)    Heading 1

```
      (Heading 1.1,Heading 1.2)
```

Is it possible to create Custom table of content based on title and subtilte? Please give your comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Aspose.Words you can create TOC using [DocumentBuilder.InsertTableOfContents](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words/documentbuilder/methods/inserttableofcontents) method. It accepts list of [TOC field’s switches](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/toc-table-of-contents-field-1f538bc4-60e6-4854-9f64-67754d78d05c) that define the final look of the Table Of Contents. If switches does not allow you to create the desired output then you can loop through paragraphs in the document, check each paragraphs style and in case of heading style compile your own TOC.